# Why the yield return value is changed that way?

Tags: python, generator, yield

```
def h():  
    print 'Wen Chuan',
    m = yield 5 # Fighting!  
    print m  
    d = yield 12  
    print 'We are together!'  
c = h()  
m = c.next() #m gets the value of yield 5
d = c.send('Fighting!') #d gets the value of yield 12
print 'We will never forget the date', m, '.', d
```

Please check above code. 
It's running result is below:

```
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
Wen Chuan Fighting!
We will never forget the date 5 . 12
```

And according to my understanding, the first yield return value is changed to "`Fighting`!" already, but why later when `print m` it still shows value 5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you are not changing what the `yield 5` expression makes the generator produce.

`.send()` will change what the local `m` *inside `h()`* will be set to only.

What happens is:

- You create `h()`, a generator function, and execution is frozen.
- You call `.next()` on the generator. Execution is resumed, `'Wen Chuan'` is printed and the code runs until the `yield 5` expression. `5` is returned and assigned to the global `m`. The generator is paused again.
- You call `c.send('Fighting!')`. Execution is resumed, `'Fighting!'` is assigned to the local variable `m` in the generator function, `print m` prints that. `yield 12` is executed, the generator is paused and `12` is assigned to the global variable `d`.
- `'We will never forget the date', 5, '.', 12` is printed.

By this point the generator function is still paused, and the last line of the generator function is never executed. If you were to call `.next()` again, then `'We are together!'` would be printed, the generator end and `StopIteration` would be raised.

Answer (score 1):

`m` inside and outside the function are distinct variables which don't affect each other.